# how to show store name in stead of branch name in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysql table named "tbl_stores" and "tbl_deals". the basic structure looks like this-

[image: mysqltable]

i want to show store name instead of branch name by store id and branch id in same table

i tried the follow code i getting store and branch names

```
$d_id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$s_id=$_REQUEST['sid'];
$sql1 = "SELECT  t1.s_id,t1.p_id,t1.store_name,t1.store_address,t1.store_city,t1.store_lat,t1.store_lng,t1.store_cat,t1.store_status,t2.deal_name,t2.deal_desc,t2.deal_end,t2.deal_type,t2.deal_m,t2.deal_n,t2.deal_op,t2.deal_dp,t2.deal_pf,t2.deal_pa,t2.deal_sa,t2.deal_fi, t2.deal_images, t2.deal_stores,t2.deal_status 
FROM tbl_stores t1, tbl_deals t2 
WHERE t1.s_id=$s_id and t2.d_id=$d_id";
```

Comment: Use a self-JOIN ON `s1.p_id = s2.s_id`.

Comment: ...or just wait a couple of minutes for *someone* to hand you the answer on a plate

Comment: @Barmar  please check my edited question

Comment: You need to join again with `tbl_stores` to go from the branch to the associated store.

Comment: @barmar can you please explain me, i tried from last 1 day i didn't get fruitful results. tq

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join `tbl_stores` with itself to get the related store from a branch.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT  t1.s_id,t1.p_id,t3.store_name,t1.store_address,t1.store_city,t1.store_lat,t1.store_lng,t1.store_cat,t1.store_status,t2.deal_name,t2.deal_desc,t2.deal_end,t2.deal_type,t2.deal_m,t2.deal_n,t2.deal_op,t2.deal_dp,t2.deal_pf,t2.deal_pa,t2.deal_sa,t2.deal_fi, t2.deal_images, t2.deal_stores,t2.deal_status 
FROM tbl_stores t1
CROSS JOIN tbl_deals t2 
JOIN tbl_stores t3 ON t1.p_id = t3.s_id
WHERE t1.s_id=$s_id and t2.d_id=$d_id";
```

If `$s_id` can be the main store rather than a branch, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` and `IFNULL()` to handle that case.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT  t1.s_id,t1.p_id,IFNULL(t3.store_name, t1.store_name) AS store_name,t1.store_address,t1.store_city,t1.store_lat,t1.store_lng,t1.store_cat,t1.store_status,t2.deal_name,t2.deal_desc,t2.deal_end,t2.deal_type,t2.deal_m,t2.deal_n,t2.deal_op,t2.deal_dp,t2.deal_pf,t2.deal_pa,t2.deal_sa,t2.deal_fi, t2.deal_images, t2.deal_stores,t2.deal_status 
FROM tbl_stores t1
CROSS JOIN tbl_deals t2 
LEFT JOIN tbl_stores t3 ON t1.p_id = t3.s_id
WHERE t1.s_id=$s_id and t2.d_id=$d_id";
```